# October Database

Tags: database, octobercms

I have this code

```
public function onRequest(){

    $users = \Db::table('engegraph_forms_membros')->get();

    foreach ($users as $part) {
        echo $part->membro;  // membro ITS NAME FROM ONE COLUMN IN MY DATABASE
    }
}
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoaWg.png)

This works on page, but I want send this to a partial, in my database I have 3 columns and I want to show the values of column there.

[Partial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH7t1.png)

I have tried many ways but I don't understand well the docs, sorry for my English. If someone help me I would be grateful.

Comment: where did you written this onRequest function ? is it on a component ??

Comment: How i do, get now ?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and provide your code as a [mcve]. It's fine if English isn't your first language (it isn't mine either), if you can show code that shows the problem and you can at least somewhat describe what you got and what you expected to get instead. (Don't post code as images, it's hard to read, links can break, and nobody wants to retype your code to try it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have this **onRequest** function on a component so write below code on it.

```
public function onRun(){

$this->page['users'] = $this->onRequest();

}

public function onRequest(){

    return \Db::table('engegraph_forms_membros')->get();

}
```

now **users** variable will be available on your page and partial.

Comment: Yes, this onrequest its on component, i will try this , ty

Comment: Okay @Erik  and if it works then please upvote the answer.

Comment: Doenst worked, but sure its my fault, i am newbie and dont undestand well inglish

Comment: I want to put each value of column on a list undestand, but i am doing something wrong